# Java Regex Assistance

Tags: java, regex, maze

This check is still failing.  I split up the conditions so I can test them.  It fails for cs = "WWWW", "WXW", "WWWWWWWWRWWWWWW"

```
/** 
 * Check to ensure all lines are only composed of walls, 
 * entrance, exit, and space
 */
protected boolean invalidMazeCharacters(CharSequence cs) {

    p = Pattern.compile("^W+R|X|\\s*W+$");
    m = p.matcher(cs);
    if (!m.matches()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: If you attached the junit testcase that is failing and the error message to this question, we wouldn't have to guess what you want to happen.

Comment: Hint: use an IDE with a good debugger and step through the statements within your method next time. You would quickly see that the CharSequence you create isn't what it should be.

Answer (score 2):

```
CharSequence cs = new String(line.toString());
```

Here you are making a string of what the array looks like. Something like "[C@333cb1eb"

Drop the 'toString()' on the line and you might get a step closer.

Comment: Outch, can't believe I missed that one - maybe because I just *expect* somebody to debug the code first.

Comment: I know. I was just about to skip this question because we don't know where it is going wrong (ie, which regex) but I spotted that gem and was quite amused.

Comment: Thanks for feedback.  If I drop the toString won't I be passing a char[] as argument? And isn't that a problem?  Thanks.

Comment: From `String(char[])` : "Allocates a new String so that it represents the sequence of characters currently contained in the character array argument. The contents of the character array are copied; subsequent modification of the character array does not affect the newly created string."

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have misunderstood the meaning of the bracket notation `[...]`. It creates a *character class*, meaning it matches exactly one character, which may be any of the characters in `...`. (There are a number of special syntaxes for more control over what characters it can match, but that's the basic idea.) So, for example, this pattern of yours:

```
^W[W{10,20}R{1}]W$
```

requires that the string be exactly three characters long; that the first character be a `W`; that the second character be a `W`, a `{`, a `1`, a `0`, a comma, a `2`, a `}`, or an `R`; and that the third character be another `W`.

In that instance, what you really should have written is just:

```
^W+RW+$
```

to ensure that the string consists entirely of `W`s except for one `R`, and that it starts and ends with `W`s. (You don't really need to worry about the number of `W`s, since by this point you've already ensured that the string is exactly 22 characters long.)

---

**Edited to add:** By the way, it's wonderful that you have unit-tests, but your method has such a narrow interface — it takes a string, performs a bunch of validations, and just returns `true` or `false` — that it's not really amenable to unit-testing. If your unit-test finds that the method wrongly returns `false` for a given string, you'll have very little information about what went wrong, so it's not much help in finding the problem. (You've already seen this for yourself.) Worse yet, if your unit-test finds that the method *correctly* returns `false` for a given string, you still have no way of being sure that it returned `false` *for the right reason*. So it doesn't help very much in making sure your code is correct. There are a few ways you can address this:

- You can create a separate method for each validation-rule, and then `checkFileValidLine` will invoke each of those methods to validate the line. That way, you can have unit-tests for those methods (in addition to cursory unit-tests for `checkFileValidLine` to make sure it's calling those methods and returning the right result). (This is the approach I'd recommend.)
- You can create an helper method that performs the same validations as the current method, but instead of returning `true` for a valid string and `false` for an invalid one, it can return `null` for a valid string and (e.g.) `"line.length != 22"` for an invalid one. Your unit-tests can then ensure that *exactly* the right validation-rule is triggered, while `checkFileValidLine` can just return `true` if that helper method returned `null`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback.  Yes the design is not by choice and is obviously not conducive to unit testing.  To be honest I will likely debug while commenting out various portions of conditional logic to isolate bugs.  This may seem pretty dumb/slow but I only have one semester under my belt.  Thanks again for the explanation this is my first regex.

Comment: @user1260392: You're welcome! But I don't understand -- what do you mean, the design is not by choice? Are you not allowed to create other methods?

Comment: I can't create public methods and I have no control over the requirements for maze creation. In fact if you look closely and if I actually used the regex correctly this code doesn't filter out a lot of bad cases such as a maze with a row that has all walls but again I can't make that decision unfortunately.

Comment: @user1260392: Unit-testing doesn't require that methods be `public`, only that they not be `private`. The unit-test can see `protected` and package-private methods as long as it's in the same package. (Usually you'd do this by having two source directories, e.g. `src` and `testsrc`. Then if your class is in `src/com/example/maze/MazeValidator.java`, your unit-test could be in `testsrc/com/example/maze/MazeValidatorTest.java`, so they're both in the `com.example.maze` package.)

Comment: Yes this is exactly how I have it setup, I will use protected to make some tests.  Thanks again.

Comment: ruakh, your answer was so insightful I was hoping you could give me some more feedback.  I have created protected methods for each condition.  I still can't get the regex for checking if all the lines are composed of walls, one entrance, one exit.   /** 
  * Check to ensure all lines are only composed of walls, 
  * entrance, exit, and space
  */
 protected boolean invalidMazeCharacters(CharSequence cs) {

  p = Pattern.compile("^W+R|X|\\s*W+$");
  m = p.matcher(cs);
  if (!m.matches()) {
   return true;
  }
  return false;
 }

Comment: sorry, thats not how I meant for it to come out, I hit return and it automatically added the comment.  I will post the code to the original code so you can see it better.

Comment: @user1260392: I think you should post that as a new question. (You can then comment here with a link.) The new code will not fit in a comment, and your new question is not really the same as this one.